Radial derivatives
Thank you for you time:
I have $x=(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb R^2$ and $v(x)=|\ln |x||^k$, for some $k$ real parameter. I want to see why $$|\nabla v|^2= (\frac{\partial \tilde{v}}{\partial r})^2$$ where $r=|x|$ and $v(x)=\tilde{v}(r)$.
My attempt is:
Well $\nabla v=(\partial_{x_1} v,\partial_{x_2}v)$ then $|\nabla v|=|(\partial_{x_1} v,\partial_{x_2}v)|=\sqrt{(\partial_{x_1} v)^2+ (\partial_{x_2} v)^2}$ .
The other hand, if i take $r=|x|$ and $v(x)=\tilde{v}(r)$ then
$(\frac{\partial \tilde{v}}{\partial r})^2= (\partial_r \tilde{v} \frac{\partial r}{\partial x_1}+\partial_r \tilde{v} \frac{\partial r}{\partial x_2})^2=(\partial_r \tilde{v}\frac{x_1}{r} + \partial_r \tilde{v}\frac{x_2}{r})^2$.
Please, how can continued this or if i am doing wrong i would like some hint. Thank you

For simplicity, assume that $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ satisfies $|x|>1$, then $v(x)=(\ln|x|)^k$. It follows that
$$
  \partial_{x_i}v=k(\ln|x|)^{k-1}\cdot \frac{1}{|x|}\cdot\frac{x_i}{|x|},\quad i=1,2.
$$
Hence, $|\nabla v|=k(\ln|x|)^{k-1}\cdot \frac{1}{|x|} = k(\ln r)^{k-1}\cdot\frac{1}{r}=\frac{d \bar{v}}{dr}$ for $\bar{v}(r) = v(x_1,x_2)$ with $r=|x|$.

Thank you, i got your answer. Perhaps do you know if the equality $|\nabla v|=(\partial_r \tilde{v}(r))^2$ is true each time that i have the variable  change $r=|x|$?  Best!!

If $v$ is radially symmetric, the equality is true.

thank you so much!!
